# efficient way of inserting into database after breaking a huge xml file

Tags: python

I need to split a Huge xml file and 
then insert into a database is this the most efficient way of doing what i am doing

Here is my code

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
filename = r'D:\test\Books.xml'
context = iter(etree.iterparse(filename, events=('start', 'end')))
_, root = next(context)
books = []
for event, elem in context:
    if event == 'start' and elem.tag == '{http://www.book.org/Book-19200/biblography}Book':
        etree.register_namespace("", "http://www.book.org/Book-19200/biblography")
        xml = etree.tostring(elem)
        xmls.append(xml)
        if len(xmls) == 100:
            populate_db(books)
            books = []
        root.clear()

def populate_db(books):
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO Books VALUES (?)', books)
```

My sample book.xml looks like this

```
<Books>
    <Book xmlns="http://www.book.org/Book-19200/biblography"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    ISBN="519292296"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.book.org/Book-19200/biblography ../../book.xsd 
    http://www.w3.org/2000/12/xmldsig# ../../xmldsig-core-schema.xsd">
        <Detail ID="67">
            <BookName>Code Complete 2</BookName>
            <Author>Steve McConnell</Author>
            <Pages>960</Pages>
            <ISBN>0735619670</ISBN>        
            <BookName>Application Architecture Guide 2</BookName>
            <Author>Microsoft Team</Author>
            <Pages>496</Pages>
            <ISBN>073562710X</ISBN>
        </Detail>
    </Book>
    <Book xmlns="http://www.book.org/Book-19200/biblography"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    ISBN="519292296"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.book.org/Book-19200/biblography ../../book.xsd 
    http://www.w3.org/2000/12/xmldsig# ../../xmldsig-core-schema.xsd">
        <Detail ID="87">
            <BookName>Rocking Python</BookName>
            <Author>Guido Rossum</Author>
            <Pages>960</Pages>
            <ISBN>0735619690</ISBN>
            <BookName>Python Rocks</BookName>
            <Author>Microsoft Team</Author>
            <Pages>496</Pages>
            <ISBN>073562710X</ISBN>
        </Detail>
    </Book>
</Books>
```

Is this approach appending to a List and using batches of 100 and inserting into the database efficient or do i need to think of multi-threading here

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how "huge" your XML file is. Megabytes or Terabytes?

It is very likely that parsing the XML file will take more time than DB insertion anyway, so don't over-engineer it. Just try your code as you have it.

Remember: *Premature optimization is the root of all evil.*

Comment: My file is approx 2Gb

Comment: As I said, just go for it. Given your example data, you'll have around 3 million DB entries, which shouldn't challenge modern DB engines. Plus, it doesn't sound like you're gonna run that program over and over again, so why do you care about the run time so much? If you'd started when you asked the question it'd already have finished.

Comment: So will it make sense to do the parsing in multiple threads then if so how do i parse it in multiple threads please

Comment: Hi Christian performance is important as i have to insert over 300 plus such files .Currently the db is down so i am waiting

Comment: Just run it and see how long it takes. By the time you'll have converted your code to use threads and made it stop crashing, the conversion would already have finished if you just ran it.

Comment: If you have multiple files, just run multiple processes (e.g. one for every CPU core), your DB wont care. Stay away from threads if you can help it, they are a pain to get right.